# Dependent Validation in Angular 6 not showing in view

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms, angular6

I am trying to display error messages if user enters password 1234 then only confirm password is mandatory.

Normal validations are working fine. only dependent validations are not showing in views.

if i debug its showing form is invalid but i am not able to show the message in the HTML page

my html page

```
 <div class="container">
   <h2>Reactive Form</h2>

      <form [formGroup]="contFrm" (ngSubmit)="submitContFrm()">


<div class="form-group">
  <label>Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submited && f.email.errors}">
  <div *ngIf="f.email.touched && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">
      Email is Requird.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submited && f.password.errors}">
  <div *ngIf="submited && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">
      Password is Requird.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="cpassword">
  <div *ngIf="submited && f.cpassword.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.cpassword.errors.required">
      Password is Requird.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 contFrm: FormGroup;
 submited = false;

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

 ngOnInit() {
 this.contFrm = this.fb.group({
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  password: ['', Validators.required],
  cpassword: ['']
  });
  this.contFrm.get('password').valueChanges.subscribe(
  (data) => this.confirmPassword(data)
  )
 }

 get f() {
   return this.contFrm.controls;
 }

 submitContFrm() {
   this.submited = true;

   if(this.contFrm.invalid) {
     return;
   }
  }

  confirmPassword(data) {
   let cpwd = this.contFrm.get('cpassword');
    if(data == "1234") {
    cpwd.clearValidators();
    cpwd.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    } else {
    cpwd.clearValidators();
    }

    cpwd.updateValueAndValidity();
   }
  }
```

Please help me out

Comment: You should use FormGroup that include both password and the confirmation, and add a group validator to this group.

Comment: Could you create a demo showcasing your issue. I tried the code you presented and it worked fine for me...

Answer (score 0):

updateValueAndValidity() doesn't recursively update the values and validity of the descendants it will only update those of the ancestors so modify your code and check

```
confirmPassword(data) {
   let cpwd = this.contFrm.get('cpassword');
    if(data == "1234") {
    cpwd.clearValidators();
    cpwd.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    } else {
    cpwd.clearValidators();
    }

    this.contFrm.updateValueAndValidity();
   }
  }
```